# Counting number of rows resulting from a nested SQL select statement with a JOIN

Tags: sql, join, count, mariadb

I have the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id), a.project_id, p.is_recommended 
FROM assessments a 
INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id=a.project_id 
WHERE p.is_recommended = 1 
GROUP BY project_id 
HAVING COUNT(a.id) >= 3
```

I would like to count the resulting number of rows.

If not for the `INNER JOIN`, all I'd have to do is something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(id), project_id
    FROM assessments 
    GROUP BY project_id 
    HAVING COUNT(id) >= 3) assessments
```

But how do I calculate the resulting number of rows if my statement has a `JOIN`? What syntax should I be using?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause is grouping by `project_id` only. Now, for a project that has multiple `p.is_recommended` values, which one do you want to pick? As it is it may pick a different one each time you run the query, yielding an unpredictable result. You probably should use `MAX()`, `MIN()`, etc. on it. As it is this is a malformed SQL query, that unfortunately MySQL accepts (and runs). Other databases would reject it at once.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: A [mre] includes cut cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(a.id), a.project_id, p.is_recommended
    FROM assessments a
    INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id=a.project_id
    WHERE p.is_recommended = 1
    GROUP BY project_id
    HAVING COUNT(a.id) >= 3
    ) AS counts
```

Comment: You are shooting the messenger. I have not berated you. There is no [mre]. I've tried to help in the context of the site goals & protocols. Good luck.